# Access Form Scrollbars won't disappear when not needed

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have multiple continuous sub-forms in a single parent form. When the number of records in the subform is small enough that the scrollbar is not need, it disappears but leaves behind a white space where it would usually be if drawn. If the subform originally is opened with the small number of records, there is no graphical issue. Seems to be a refresh/repaint issue but that isn't working. Any pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Have read that it may have to do with margins/anchors but all steps down that path have turned up nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to handle this is to essentially reload the sub-form by...

1. Save the SQL string representing for the recordsource property of the sub-form to a string variable.
2. Set the SourceObject property of the sub-form container to "".
3. Set the SourceObject property of the sub-form container back to the original name.
4. Set the recordsource property of the sub-form = to the string variable in step 1.

This should remove the grey area previously occupied by the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Check the record count.  Set the scroll bar accordingly...

```
Me.Scrollbars = 0 ' to not show them.

Me.Scrollbars = 1 ' for horizontal only

Me.Scrollbars = 2 ' for vertical only 

Me.Scrollbars = 3 ' for both horizontal and vertical
```

Comment: Have tried this but unfortunately it is the same issue, the scroll bar itself will disappear when set to 0 but the space that it occupied is not reclaimed. Leaves a white block down the side of my otherwise all black form.

Comment: @TrudyTech Posted an alternate solution.

Comment: What happens if you make your form 0.25 inches wider than the container that holds it while keeping the horizontal scroll bar setting = 2? Secondly, is reloading the continuous form not an option when the record count changes?

Comment: Have tried making the form bigger than the container, did not work as intended. Your answer of reloading the form was the path I took and was the only way i managed to solve the issue. Not super thrilled it came down to that as there is alot of data but it worked. Thanks alot for your help.